# Not able to run Microsoft Bing Speech Recognition API on iOS device using iOS Client Sample provided by Microsoft

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, bing-api, microsoft-speech-api

I was trying to explore Microsoft's Bing Speech Recognition API for iOS https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-iOS. I followed all the steps written in the read me. The app runs and it seems to be detecting the speech from microphone and sending it to the Microsoft server but it gives an error in the logs and the button disables itself without giving any text on the app.
Here are the logs that came in the console. Please help.

```html
Application Name: com.Microsoft.SpeechRecognitionServerExample/1.0.1
Refreshing token /sts/v1.0/issueToken
Initializing Audio Services
Initializing Speech Services
No application id provided to controller
GetIdentityPropertyValue 3
Useragent Value iOS Assistant (iOS; 10.0.1;Mobile;ProcessName/AppName=com.Microsoft.SpeechRecognitionServerExample/1.0.1;DeviceType=Near;SpeechClient=1.0.160824)
Url: 'https://websockets.platform.bing.com/ws/speech/recognize'
Locale: 'en-us'
Application Id: ''
Version: 4.0.150429
UserAuthorizationToken: 
ServerLoggingLevel: 1
Initiating websocket connection. m_connection=0x0 host=websockets.platform.bing.com port=443
Auth token status: 200
Authorization token hr 0 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc3BlZWNoLnBsYXRmb3JtLmJpbmcuY29tIiwic3Vic2NyaXB0aW9uLWlkIjoiZmNlYThiNTE3NGZmNDdkODk4ZWZiN2ZjYzNjZjM4MzMiLCJwcm9kdWN0LWlkIjoiQmluZy5TcGVlY2guUHJldmlldyIsImNvZ25pdGl2ZS1zZXJ2aWNlcy1lbmRwb2ludCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXBpLmNvZ25pdGl2ZS5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL2ludGVybmFsL3YxLjAvIiwiYXp1cmUtcmVzb3VyY2UtaWQiOiIiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bXMuY29nbml0aXZlc2VydmljZXMiLCJhdWQiOiJ1cm46bXMuc3BlZWNoIiwiZXhwIjoxNDc1NDg3MDQ1fQ.4LF0gyhXU0T1iwDahlYlanKJ_wVjOOLhLyalFeDqIzA' 
Successfully initialized client connection
Create ImpressionId: f43586374f8d8e455e48b090f2aaa5cd
Create ImpressionId: f627a603daa0cd4a16f59d9581118cdd
Reset

Create ImpressionId: dad2c09e82b8eaaacec3b20890de9bb8
ImpressionId: a9776c0ba8dc079c7d9658e6746a46ea
Adding requestId: 'bf17eb3310b2e39944d85dfe3d2868eb' for 'text/cu.client.context'
Subscribing request [bf17eb3310b2e39944d85dfe3d2868eb]
Waiting for connection/send completion.
Audio stream created
Adding requestId: 'dd3d699f39139326bedbb1dafd8816fb' for 'audio/x-wav'
Subscribing request [dd3d699f39139326bedbb1dafd8816fb]
Audio Stream Created
Creating transcoder 2

Microphone permissions: 0
Upgrade request returned with HTTP status code: 101.
Web socket handshake completed
CU Client connected
ConnectionStateChanged
Sent first chunk of audio stream, requestId='dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Received message: 'audio.stream.response'
Response request id: 'dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Response impression: 'a9776c0b-a8dc-079c-7d96-58e6746a46ea'

LanguageGeneration OK
Received message: 'audio.stream.response'
Response request id: 'dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Response impression: 'a9776c0b-a8dc-079c-7d96-58e6746a46ea'

LanguageGeneration OK
Received message: 'audio.stream.response'
Response request id: 'dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Response impression: 'a9776c0b-a8dc-079c-7d96-58e6746a46ea'

LanguageGeneration OK
Received message: 'audio.stream.response'
Response request id: 'dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Response impression: 'a9776c0ba8dc079c7d9658e6746a46ea'
Response Conversation: 'ab7082f3c4de8feb0d6210e8ec07dcb3'

LanguageGeneration OK

Sending audio stream endpoint, requestId='dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
Sent audio stream endpoint, requestId='dd3d699f-3913-9326-bedb-b1dafd8816fb'
signaling OnAudioEvent(AUDIO_EVENT_RECORD_STOP)
originating error 0x80070057
Client UPL: 32880000 ticks
originating error 0x8000ffff
originating error 0x80070057
originating error 0x80004005
originating error 0x80004005
Failed to 'hresult', HR=80004005, WebSocket connection failed
No messages to retry, closing.
Closing web socket channel
CU Client connection dropped
ConnectionStateChanged
WebSocket closed unexpectedly, status: 0
Web socket channel already closed.
```